# jsTree get siblings of a node

Tags: jstree, jstree-dnd

I'm using drag and drop with jsTree, and when I drag a node to a new position, I have to update not only its position, but the positions of its siblings too in the database.

Here's an example:

[image: img1]

If I drag `New node` into node `Gamme 1`, now it's siblings are `gamme 501` and `gamme 500`

[image: img2]

Getting data about the moved node and updating it's position in db is not a problem:

```
.on("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('saveGammeNewPosition'),
        data: {
            gammeId: data.node.id,
            newParentId: data.node.parent,
            position: data.position
        }
    });
})
```

But I have no idea how to get information about the new siblings of a node that has been moved.

When I do something like this, unfortunately I get no data on position as the json jsTree accepts has no position attribute:

```
$('#tree').jstree(true).get_json(data.node.parent, {flat: true})
```

So is there a way I can get data on positions of the siblings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the new parent of the node in the move_node event and use that to get its immediate children.

```
function getSiblings(nodeID, parent) {
    var tree = $('#tree').jstree(true),
        parentNode = tree.get_node(parent),
        aChildren = parentNode.children,
        aSiblings = [];

    aChildren.forEach(function(c){
        if(c !== nodeID) aSiblings.push(c);
    });
    return aSiblings;
}

$('#tree').on("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var aSiblings = getSiblings(data.node.id, data.parent);
    console.log(aSiblings);
});
```

Comment: `aChildren` was enough for me to work towards a solution. thank you for your help!